# How to solve Memory Limit in C

Tags: arrays, c, memory-limit

i have problem where the constraint have to be 10e9 but every time i ran the code it always resulted as Memory Limit, is there away to overcome this issue ?

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int arr = 10e9;
    int data[arr];
    int a;
    int n,t;
    
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int max = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < arr; j++){
            data[j] = 0;
        }
        
        scanf("%d",&t);
        for(int j = 0; j < t; j++){
            scanf("%d", &a);
            data[a]++;
            if(max < data[a]){
                max = data[a];
            }
        }
        int min = arr;
        for(int k = 0; k < arr; k++){
            
            if(min > k && data[k] == max){
                min = k;
            }
        }
    
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n%d\n", i+1, max,min);
    
        }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 10e9 is ten billion. The size of an `int` is typically 4 bytes. So you are trying to create an array of 40 billion bytes. Unless you have a machine with 64GB of memory, there's no hope that this is going to work. If you *do* have 64GB, then you should use `malloc(10e9 * sizeof(int))` to allocate the memory for the array.

Comment: ...Unless you have a machine with 64GB of virtual .memory.  A 64-bit OS should handle that OK, assuming swap space is available.

Comment: Rethink your algorithm. Apparently you should trace the minimum and maximum of a sequence of numbers. Are you sure you need an array for this? (Hint: you do not.) Presumably the limit was given to you to make you choose an appropriate data type for the loop counter.

Comment: @user3386109: A process’ virtual memory may exceed the computer’s physical memory. The virtual memory does not all have to be mapped to physical memory at the same time. It can be swapped in and out as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a 10e9 int array, in other words, a 40GB array in your stack. A stack typically only has 700KB to 1MB.

If your RAM does have more than 40GB of space, including after accounting for the OS and other background processes, then you can do `int *data = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10e4)`(don't forget to free it at the end with `free(data)`). `malloc` allocates your memory at the heap, which is meant for storing such large things.

Btw, your RAM has to be at least 64GB for this to work. Your OS might make some hard disk cache and make it work somehow, but please don't attempt this assault to your computer if you have less than 64GB RAM.